# How to add watermark in different location of image when upload using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have added code like below to add watermark in center of image:

```
if (!is_dir('assets/uploads_image/')) {
    mkdir('assets/uploads_image/', 0777, true);
}
if (!is_dir('assets/uploads_watermark_image/')) {
    mkdir('assets/uploads_watermark_image/', 0777, true);
}
$config1['upload_path']   = 'assets/uploads_image/'; 
$config1['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg|svg';
$this->load->library('upload', $config1);
$this->upload->initialize($config1);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error['error']);
     redirect('photographer/uploadimage');
}
$config['upload_path']   = 'assets/uploads_watermark_image/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg|svg';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
$_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['image']['error'];
$_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$config['source_image'] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/img/overlay_watermark.png';
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
$config['wm_opacity'] = '100';
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->watermark();
```

Now I want to modify this code and need to add watermark image into all corners and center of image. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using CodeIgniter 2: https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/image_lib.html

So it would appear you need to add each watermark one at a time.

Here is your code sample slightly revised to first define all the locations you want watermarks and then a loop to add the watermark to each location (based on the idea that you want the same watermark in each location).

```
// YOUR SETUP CODE

if (!is_dir('assets/uploads_image/')) {
    mkdir('assets/uploads_image/', 0777, true);
}
if (!is_dir('assets/uploads_watermark_image/')) {
    mkdir('assets/uploads_watermark_image/', 0777, true);
}
$config1['upload_path']   = 'assets/uploads_image/'; 
$config1['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg|svg';
$this->load->library('upload', $config1);
$this->upload->initialize($config1);
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
     $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error['error']);
     redirect('photographer/uploadimage');
}
$config['upload_path']   = 'assets/uploads_watermark_image/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|jpg|svg';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);

// YOUR WATERMARK SETUP CODE

$config['image_library'] = 'GD2';
$_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['image']['error'];
$_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$config['source_image'] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/img/overlay_watermark.png';
$config['wm_opacity'] = '100';
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);


// DEFINE YOUR WATERMARK LOCATIONS

$watermark_array = array(
    array('horizontal' => 'center', 'vertical' => 'middle'),
    array('horizontal' => 'left', 'vertical' => 'top'),
    array('horizontal' => 'right', 'vertical' => 'top'),
    array('horizontal' => 'left', 'vertical' => 'bottom'),
    array('horizontal' => 'right', 'vertical' => 'bottom')
);


// ADD YOUR WATERMARKS

foreach ($watermark_array as $row) {
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = $row['vertical'];
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = $row['horizontal'];

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
    $this->image_lib->watermark();
}
```